# Can't set an object in a recursive method

Tags: c#, recursion, methods, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to add a node to a binary search tree.
Here's a bit where two nodes are compared - the node you want to add and a node in your tree (first time its root).

```
    ...
    Compare(newNode, tree.root);
    ...

    public static void Compare(Node newN, Node comN)
        {
            if (comN == null)
            {
                comN = newN;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (newN.data < comN.data)
                { Compare(newN, comN.left); }
                else if (newN.data > comN.data)
                { Compare(newN, comN.right); }
                else if (newN == comN)
                    return;
            }
        }
        // .data = int value of the node
```

When I step through:

In the "comN = newN;" part, the node is set. However, after "return;" it jumps back up a level and the left/right node (the node we set earlier) is still set to null.

Any suggestions? (Sorry for possibly incorrect use of terminology, I'm a newbie)

Comment: You can't change what `comN` refers to without the `ref` keyword.

Comment: You can fix this with the `ref` keyword, but that just makes your code even harder to reason about. Could you give a plain English description of what your method is supposed to do?

Comment: I suggest you learn about "pass by value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to how C# passes parameters, by default, you're working with a local reference. Setting `comN` to `newN` doesn't copy values: it sets your local reference to the same object, without updating the reference in the calling code. You can get the expected behavior by changing your code as follows:

```
Compare(newNode, ref tree.root);
...

public static void Compare(Node newN, ref Node comN)
    {
        if (comN == null)
        {
            comN = newN;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (newN.data < comN.data)
            { Compare(newN, ref comN.left); }
            else if (newN.data > comN.data)
            { Compare(newN, ref comN.right); }
            else if (newN == comN)
                return;
        }
    }
```

See [Passing Reference-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) for more information on reference types and parameters.

Comment: This could also be handled without the `ref` keyword by assigning to `comN.left` or `comN.right` as the final terminating condition.

Comment: I agree with @crashmstr. Sure this will work, but you have just assisted the OP down a path of bad coding practice. Much better to have shown them how to achieve this without the `ref` keyword.

Comment: @DavidArno: That's fair, and generally I tend towards education about what smells bad about the code, but he did specifically ask about setting references in methods (that will propagate up), so I answered that question. I do agree that this is slightly awkward (there's a reason why you're forced to use the ref keyword when using such a method: you know there will be side-effects), but, I don't work with data trees all that much, and didn't comment due to lack of knowledge in that domain.

Comment: @DavidArno I don't necessarily agree that there is anything wrong with using `ref` here. Many textbooks even use a ref parameter when teaching the algorithm.

Comment: @Asad it would be way better to use a better function name and return a value instead though (or at least use a better function name than `Compare`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to call this class `BST` instead of `Node` because it makes what is going on a bit clearer. Assuming it is defined to accept a `data` and a left and right node as arguments:

```
// C# 6 for brevity
class BST
{
    public int Data { get; }
    public BST Left { get; }
    public BST Right { get; }

    public Bst(int data, BST left, BST right) 
    {
        Data = data;
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
    }
}
```

Your insert algorithm could be defined as follows:

```
static class BSTExtensions
{
    public static BST Insert(this BST bst, BST n)
    {
        if (bst == null)
            return n;

        if (n.Data < bst.Data)
            return new BST(bst.Data, bst.Left.Insert(n), bst.Right);
        if (n.Data > bst.Data)
            return new BST(bst.Data, bst.Left, bst.Right.Insert(n));

        return bst;
    }
}
```

It's fairly easy to understand what is going on here.

1. If the node you were supposed to compare against is non existent, this is the spot the new node is supposed to occupy.
2. If the value of the new node is less than the value in the current node, insert into the left subtree.
3. If the value of the new node is bigger than in the current node, insert into the right subtree.
4. If the values are equal (the only remaining possiblity), no change is needed. Just return the original tree.

While I've also made the tree in this example immutable, if you implement setters in your class you can do this a bit more efficiently, while still not requiring `ref`.